# How to select the SQL data from just 20 days using the TimeStamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timestamp, sql-timestamp

How can i just use the data of the previous 20 days using the TimeStamp. In the below code i am selecting the Timestamp anything above this timstamp i wanted to select and later insert it. But i not interested in all the data which is in database but i need the data of 20 days from that particular timestamp date.  How can i achieve it. What i tried is in below.

My SQL server query is as follows:

```
SELECT [LogID]
      ,[TimeStamp]
      ,[Artikel_Nr]
      ,[Percentage_Nr]
from [Database1].[dbo].[Tabel1]
  where [TimeStamp] > 2018-02-12 06:02:18.77 AND SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-20,GETDATE())
```

I am not sure the above line for selecting last 20 days i right. If not please correct me.

Comment: `[server1].[dbo].[Database1]` makes no sense. The first object is the database, second the Schema, and 3rd the object in the database and Schema (I.e. a Table, View). If you were using 4 part naming, then the first part would be the server name.

Comment: @Larnu: Sorry my bad, it is [Database1].[dbo].[Tabel1]. I will edit my content. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The will be an error on `SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-20,GETDATE())` you can use `DATEADD(DAY,-20,GETDATE())` directly.

If you want to previous 20 days you can try between the start day and end date.

1. start day previous 20 days `DATEADD(DAY,-20,GETDATE())`
2. end date only use `GETDATE()` to get current datetime.

then use `Between`

```
SELECT [LogID]
      ,[TimeStamp]
      ,[Artikel_Nr]
      ,[Percentage_Nr]
from [server1].[dbo].[Database1]
where [TimeStamp]  between DATEADD(DAY,-20,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime = GETDATE(); -- Specify the date you want to end at
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = DATEADD(DAY, -20, @EndDate);

SELECT [LogID]
  ,[TimeStamp]
  ,[Artikel_Nr]
  ,[Percentage_Nr]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [TimeStamp] > @StartDate AND [TimeStamp] <= @EndDate
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = DATEADD(DAY, -20, @ EndDate)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query: You don't need to select

```
SELECT [LogID]
      ,[TimeStamp]
      ,[Artikel_Nr]
      ,[Percentage_Nr]
from [server1].[dbo].[Database1]
  where [TimeStamp] > '2018-02-12 06:02:18.77' AND [TimeStamp]< DATEADD(DAY,-20,GETDATE())
```